# Use str_extract_all to extract pattern as a hashtag from a text

Tags: r, twitter, vector, character, stringr

I have a problem with the function of the package "stringr": str_extract_all
I want extract a pattern (in my case hashtags) in a character vector. My data are:

```
'data.frame':   2858732 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ created_at           : Factor w/ 995761 levels "Fri Sep 12 00:00:00 +0000 2014",..: 164928 164929 164931 164931 164932 164937 164938 164938 164940 164940 ...
 $ favorite_count       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ favorited            : Factor w/ 1 level "false": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ id                   : num  5.09e+17 5.09e+17 5.09e+17 5.09e+17 5.09e+17 ...
 $ id_str               : num  5.09e+17 5.09e+17 5.09e+17 5.09e+17 5.09e+17 ...
 $ in_reply_to_status_id: Factor w/ 747393 levels "11111569142",..: 747393 747393 7983 747393 747393 7893 747393 7994 747393 747393 ...
 $ in_reply_to_user_id  : Factor w/ 594092 levels "1000001311","1000004054",..: 594092 594092 283452 594092 594092 39362 594092 87635 594092 594092 ...
 $ lang                 : Factor w/ 60 levels "am","ar","bg",..: 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 ...
 $ retweet_count        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ retweeted            : Factor w/ 1 level "false": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ text                 : chr  "RT directe indirectecat Una nit dencartellada o perqu guanyarem http//tco/Sp09q6MVvq" "RT manelmarquez Grande TeresaForcadesF PConstituentLos poderosos no slo estn en Espaa tambin en Catalunya 9N2014 11S2014 htt" "AnastasyHope mas vale suspiro sino todo seria culpa mia aparco y quito las llaves del contacto" "RT VyvyanBasterd No s qu collons em passa avui per m'acabo de llevar amb una trempera sobrenatural vaig a aprofitar per a despe"| __truncated__ ...
 $ user_screen_name     : Factor w/ 3022692 levels "000000000096_",..: 929035 441496 1110467 741648 256996 569276 152104 2716367 2755620 2657050 ...
 $ created              : POSIXct, format: "2014-09-08 07:59:40" "2014-09-08 07:59:41" ...
 $ created.day          : POSIXct, format: "2014-09-08" "2014-09-08" ...
 $ created.hours        : POSIXct, format: "2014-09-08 08:00:00" "2014-09-08 08:00:00" ...
```

and my script:

```
doc0_hashtags = str_extract_all(doc0_hash$text, "#\\w+")
```

the function work but not well. The output is all charcter(0). How can I correct it?
I try with another method to extract hashtags with this function:

```
extract.hashes = function(vec){

  hash.pattern = "#[[:alpha:]]+"
  have.hash = grep(x = vec, pattern = hash.pattern)

  hash.matches = gregexpr(pattern = hash.pattern,
                          text = vec[have.hash])
  extracted.hash = regmatches(x = vec[have.hash], m = hash.matches)

  df = data.frame(table(tolower(unlist(extracted.hash))))
  colnames(df) = c("tag","freq")
  df = df[order(df$freq,decreasing = TRUE),]
  return(df)
}
```

But when I use it I have an error as output like this:

```
dat = head(extract.hashes(as.matrix(doc0_hash$text)),50)


Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("tag", "freq")) :
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

My data is like this:

```
dput(head(doc0$text))

c("RT directe indirectecat Una nit dencartellada o perqu guanyarem http//tco/Sp09q6MVvq",
"RT manelmarquez Grande TeresaForcadesF PConstituentLos poderosos no slo estn en Espaa tambin en Catalunya 9N2014 11S2014 htt",
"AnastasyHope mas vale suspiro sino todo seria culpa mia aparco y quito las llaves del contacto",
"RT VyvyanBasterd No s qu collons em passa avui per m'acabo de llevar amb una trempera sobrenatural vaig a aprofitar per a despertar",
"RT FIL0S0FIA El amor no se manifiesta en el deseo de acostarse con alguien sino en el deseo de dormir junto a alguien",
"MMjencarlos no es   sino bulgaro Pero las dos idiomas se parecen"
)
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Use `dput` on the relevant parts of the data with `head` to make a reproducible example.  Also you may be interested in the function `rm_hash(, extract=TRUE)` from the **qdapRegex** package.  PS I think your error comes from in that some tweets have more than one hash tag.  You need to figure out how to store differently.  But not sure without data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I try to use this package now and it doesn't find hashtags in my text, i think it is impossible this situation, my dataset is too big.

Comment: I don't see any hashtags (i.e. `#abc`) in the text you provided.  Thats why you get `character(0)` and `rm_hash` do not work.  There's nothing to extract.

Comment: Agree w/ Tyler. Voting to close as not reproducible user error.